# How do I remove element from a list of tuple if the 2nd item in each tuple is a duplicate?

Tags: python, list, sorting, duplicates, tuples

How do I remove element from a list of tuple if the 2nd item in each tuple is a duplicate?

For example, I have a list sorted by 1st element that looks like this:

```
alist = [(0.7897897,'this is a foo bar sentence'),
(0.653234, 'this is a foo bar sentence'),
(0.353234, 'this is a foo bar sentence'),
(0.325345, 'this is not really a foo bar'),
(0.323234, 'this is a foo bar sentence'),]
```

The desired output leave the tuple with the highest 1st item, should be:

```
alist = [(0.7897897,'this is a foo bar sentence'),
(0.325345, 'this is not really a foo bar')]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `alist` is already sorted by the first element from highest to lowest:

```
alist = [(0.7897897,'this is a foo bar sentence'),
(0.653234, 'this is a foo bar sentence'),
(0.353234, 'this is a foo bar sentence'),
(0.325345, 'this is not really a foo bar'),
(0.323234, 'this is a foo bar sentence'),]

seen = set()
out = []
for a,b in alist:
    if b not in seen:
        out.append((a,b))
        seen.add(b)
```

`out` is now:

```
[(0.7897897, 'this is a foo bar sentence'),
 (0.325345, 'this is not really a foo bar')]
```

Comment: @Junuxx I guess it's wise to infer that this list is incidentally sorted, but it is not guaranteed that everytime it will be sorted.

Comment: @Junuxx - you're right. The most interesting part has been done by OP. Then it is just a boring loop.

Comment: @heltonbiker - the OP alrady has "I have a list sorted by 1st element" - I did not realize it first.

Comment: (well, actually the OP stated that the list is ALREADY sorted...)

Comment: i was already doing that, but i thought there might be a cleaner way of doing this without creating new sets or list =)